# specflow hooks between two given steps

Tags: specflow

i have the following specflow test:

```
@done   
@succesfulladdbeforewhen
Scenario Outline: Admin adds an alternate numbers entry with a phonenumber successfully
    Given the BW User is logged in with a <userlevel> Level Account
        And the AddAlternateNumbersEntry query parameter contains an existing userid within the scope of the BW User
        And the AddAlternateNumbersEntry post body contains an available phonenumber
    When the BW User submits the AddAlternateNumbersEntry request
    Then HTTP 201 should be returned
    And a new alternate numbers entry should be added

    Examples: User Levels
            | userlevel         |
            | System            |
            | Service Provider  |
            | Group             |
```

However i want a hook between before the second "and" (And the AddAlternateNumbersEntry post body contains an available phonenumber)

How can i do this ??? i can't find the propper kind of code/hook to do it with. thnx for the advice

thnx

Comment: explain better what you need, please :)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you explained what you are trying to achieve